# Issue with returnUrl after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Controller has `Authorize` attribute and two actions for get and post

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController
{
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Edit(int id){
  ...
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Edit(MyModel model){
  ...
  }
}
```

When session is expired and user submit form, then `returnUrl` contains `MyController.Edit` (without id) and tries to redirect to it after login. As I have required `id` parameter in get action I have following error

> System.ArgumentException The parameters dictionary contains a null
>   entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for
>   method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult.Edit(Int32).

Is there any common solution for this issue? I don't want all my get actions have *nullable* `id` parameter and check if it has value.

Edit: My form html looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "MyConroller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = Model.IsReadonly ? "ro-container" : "track-changes"}))
{}
```

Comment: Is the id needed? Cause if not just remove it.

Comment: Hmm, if I can get url with id, then it will solve my error :)

Comment: Alex, id is used to get entity and render edit form :)

Comment: Including ID into form action URL should resolve it.

Comment: serhiyb, Authorize attribute doesn't know anything about id, it redirects to login page. As current action is MyController/Edit it just fill in returnUrl.

Comment: The only way to solve this problem is to make the post action use the ID on the URL as well.

Comment: Please show us how  user submit form

Comment: MegaTron, I edited my question. I understood that I can solve it by using id in my form action. So I need to update all form tags through application :(.